# ChartJs Bargraph not showing correct values in y axis

Tags: asp.net-core, chart.js

I have a bargraph loaded dynamically with chart js and asp.net core. i am trying to populate the yaxis value from json object, but it is always giving me value one.

Below is my requirement and code

[image]

i want to plot 'Day' in x axis and 'TotalActual' in y axis, please find my code below

```
var WeeklyData = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.UDTSLDDailyPVA.ToList()))
        console.log(WeeklyData);

        let weeklylabels = [...new Set(WeeklyData.map((x) => x.Day))];
        console.log(weeklylabels);
        
        var weeklydatasets = WeeklyData.map(y => y.TotalActual);

        
       
        var barChartDataWeekly = {
            labels: weeklylabels,
            datasets: [{
                data:weeklydatasets,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 154, 221, 1)'                    
                ]
            }],
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctxUPHHistory = document.getElementById('barChartUPHHistory').getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctxUPHHistory, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartDataWeekly,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize:50
                                //// Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                //callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                //    return value + '%';
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

But the y axis value is always showing as 1, Appreciate any help on this.

------------------UPDATED-------------------------------

```
var WeeklyData = @Html.Raw(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.UDTSLDDailyPVA.ToList()))
        console.log(WeeklyData);

        let weeklylabels = [...new Set(WeeklyData.map((x) => x.Day))];
        console.log(weeklylabels);
        
        let weeklydatasets = (WeeklyData.map((y) => y.TotalActual));
        console.log(weeklydatasets);
        
       
        var barChartDataWeekly = {
            labels: weeklylabels,
            datasets: [{
                data: WeeklyData,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(0, 154, 221, 1)'                    
                ]
            }],
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            var ctxUPHHistory = document.getElementById('barChartUPHHistory').getContext("2d");
            window.myBar = new Chart(ctxUPHHistory, {
                type: 'bar',
                data: barChartDataWeekly,
                options: {
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: false,
                    parsing: {
                        xAxisKey: 'Day',
                        yAxisKey: 'TotalActual'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        y: {
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                stepSize:50
                                //// Include a dollar sign in the ticks
                                //callback: function (value, index, ticks) {
                                //    return value + '%';
                                //}
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    plugins: {
                        legend: {
                            display: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        };
```

Comment: Tested your first code & second code. It works fine. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9cpasp?file=index.html)

Comment: @Yong Shun, Sorry! My Bad, my chartjs was conflicting with another js file. When i commented that file everything works fine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [parsing property](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/data-structures.html), such as :

```js
options: {
  ...
  parsing : {
    xAxisKey : 'Day',
    yAxisKey : 'TotalActual'
  },
}
```

[Here's an example](https://codepen.io/Frixionder/pen/XWOJBrR?editors=1010)

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, i have tried this but no changes in my bargraph. one doubt the can i pass the WeeklyData variable directly to dataset. i have updated my code with recent changes above.Please advice.

Comment: could you please advise on this?

Comment: Sorry! My Bad, my chartjs was conflicting with another js file. When i commented that file everything works fine. Thank you!